# Controlling the placement of <nav> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, nav

*Update: I tried to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lca6ayna/) visualising the issue, let me know if it is not working...*

Inspired by a tutorial as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/website/web_spa_navigation.asp) I decided to make a tabs menu for my website, as it looks really awesome. And indeed it does, except (apparently) when I am the one making it. I want to tabs located directly over my content `<div>` and both are wrapped in a wrapper `<div>` to control their placement and width. The problem is that the `<nav>` element with my menu is around 40-ish pixels too far to the right and has a space of around 20-ish pixels between it, and the content `<div>`. The code is as following:

```js
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
 "<ul id='menu'>" +
 "<li><a href='Index.html'>Ejendomme</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='Customers.html'>Opgaver</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='About.html'>Administrer</a></li>" +
 "</ul>";
```

```css
// CSS Code for the menu
ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: block;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

// CSS Code for the wrapper and content div
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: none;
}

#content {
    //position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left:  15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
<!-- Tabs menu -->
<nav id="nav01"></nav>
   
<div id="content">
  <!--- Content goes here -->
</div>

<script src="./script/script.js"></script>
```

I have Googled the issue, and I have read a bunch of stuff, but I have not yet been able to really understand what it is that I am doing wrong? Really hope you guys can help me on that.

Comment: It's always a good idea to add a http://jsfiddle.net/ so that other can see what you mean, change to code until it works and send back a new fiddle.

Comment: My first suggestion is that you add w3schools.com to your Personal Blocklist (or any other search result blocking extension). Second, I agree with @MarcelBurkhard - add a jsfiddle.

Comment: Interesting: when I try this code within jsfiddle it works just fine, but with "Run code snippet" it behaves like you stated... Did you close your wrapper-div?

Comment: I tried adding a JSFiddle, I hope it works. Out of curiosity, why don't we like w3schools? And what do we like them? :-)

Comment: Or, add a snippet right here in the post, as I've done with your question. People can copy the snippet to their answers, edit the code, etc. without worrying about an external link. Take the reflexive "add a fiddle!" comments (which will show up on everything you ever ask that's even vaguely web-related) with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Noceo read this: http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fey0dcap/

Comment: sry I meant padding, not margin

Comment: This fixes the placement too far to the right. It does not seem to change the vertical spacing between the menu and the content area.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of your CSS file

```
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
nav#nav01{
    padding: 0;
}
```

to your css. This will get you rid of the navigations offset.

Answer (score 1):

This works   [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lca6ayna/3/)

Added

```
#nav01{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#menu:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

^ Try this. I haven't tested it though!

**edit:** tested :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of multiple things, and many of the answers here helped solve the problem. I suggest reading them all if you experience a similar problem. First of all adding the following to the CSS helped remove any unnecessary offsets in the `<nav>` field (thanks Markai):

```
nav#nav01{
    padding: 0;
}
```

The remainder of the issue related to the padding in `ul#menu` in the CSS. I added a 9 pixels *vertical* padding and a 0 pixel *horizontal* padding. Combined with the 1 pixel border I also added, this gives a combined vertical offset of 10 pixels, matching the vertical padding in `ul#menu li a` placing the tabs perfectly where they should be. Here is the changed parts of the CSS:

```
nav#nav001 {
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 0px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

Or you can see the full code and effect in the much hated, much loved [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lca6ayna/2/) that I have created. Thank you very much for you help everyone!